# API23:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

Tags: android

thank you for coming.Today just on MacOS used ReactNative development environment.When performing the run - android, has been an error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

I really don't know where is wrong.
This is my SDKManager configuration[SDK Platforms configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgig.png)[SDK Tools Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDRZ1.png)
This is my unusual screenshots:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
Total time: 9.128 secs

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

build.gradle file

```
projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```